# Can an Int array be given a value for all numbers in the array?

Tags: java, arrays, int

```
int[] high = {2,3,4,5,6};
```

Can the array be given a constantly value of say -1? To clearify {2,3,4,5,6} all equal -1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`Arrays.fill(int[] a, int val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29) method from `java.util.Arrays`, which fills array `a` with value `val`.
In your case:

```
int[] high = new int[5]; 
Arrays.fill(high, -1);
```